# Advanced SWT Browser widget

Tags: java, browser, widget, swt

Are there advanced SWT Browser [widgets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/)?

The [documentation says](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html)

> IMPORTANT: This class is not intended to be subclassed.

UPDATE. [We](http://github.com/nodeclipse/) are developing [Eclipse-based Node.js IDE](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-blog#repositories), and I am researching on what are there good new things around. Because the project is new, we don't have to support 3.4-like Eclipse versions. And I hope to find some high level component and framework to use. But of course they should be free to develop and distribute.

This particular question focus is to try to integrate some pure JavaScript tools, that are emerging.
Some are Node.js applications or web resources.

Comment: It might be useful to explain what you're trying to do, and why the built-in Browser widget isn't sufficient.

Comment: I think I'd start by using the built-in browser, and then looking for alternatives if I found something specific that it couldn't do. For example, by using a LocationListener if you want the HTML page to be able to trigger some action/behaviour in Eclipse.

Comment: This is the Javadoc of the latest version of SWT.  Good luck.  http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/package-summary.html

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The browser API is in a different package: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/package-summary.html

There you'll see Browser, and the LocationListener interface I mentioned.